# Is SQL Server .Net application or C++ (VC++ windows SDK) application? My guess is definitely something Native so .Net code calling something native?

Tags: c++, .net, sql-server, interop, winapi

When we install SQL Server it does not ask to install **.Net Framework** but all latest version of Windows have .Net installed by default. I recently did some programming (in C#) against SSIS engine and I saw following DLLs.

[image]

Now I could just refer this DLL in .Net project and start calling functionality from it... I did not needed to do any Inter-op. My understanding is this all are .Net DLLs SQL Server engine will also be using them so is it a .Net application?

I am looking for this information as I was wondering  for Performance we go for native (Windows SDK) as .Net Frameworks SDK comes with overhead for Stability and definitely Enterprise RDBMS needs to show performance.

Comment: What makes these dlls special that you would want to use them? What functionality do you think they have?

Comment: @ildjarn you can acess SQL Server features pro-grammatically and create wrappers (with added functionality) on it. Following application uses some of those DLLs. http://insight.codeplex.com/

Comment: When you install SQL Server you install a lot of applications. Some are native some are managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 and up have started supporting .NET object internally.  You can reference .NET assemblies, etc.

You do need the .NET framework to install SQL Server.

However, the core database engine of SQL Server is still written in native code.